# General advice to regulate voltage in microcontroler and "high amp" peripherials

Tags: power, mosfet, batteries, voltage-regulator, avr

### Background

- I want to control a ws2812b 16x16 RGB LED matrix and a buzzer with an AVR ATTINY84-20PU board (programmed with an arduino).
- I want to power everything with a battery. Which? hopefully some combination of AA batteries will suffice, otherwise I'm happy to go down the 18650 route again.
- Ideal solutions should be simple enough for me to understand and learn (if possible) and be available in SMD format as I'm designing a PCB.

### Issue

- The LED matrix and the buzzer draw **together** too much power from the microcontroler to handle. Although they work if they are individually driven by the microcontroler.
- The voltage supplied from the battery will drop with time.

### Observations

- It is clear that I need to power either the LED matrix or/and the buzzer separately from the microcontroler and let the arduino only handle the control.
- It is clear that I need to somehow regulate the voltage from the battery to a constant 5V (as everything is rated 5V).

### Questions

- I have seen that I can use a SMD 5V linear voltage regulator like the L78M05ABDT-TR but is rated for 500mA (maybe a bit low?) and the minimun input voltage is too high at 10V. I will probably be looking at a range of 5V-12V input voltage. Any ideas on what I could use?
- To control the buzzer on/off, I have read that I could use a MOSFET like BSS84 but Im fairly new to MOSFETs so Im unsure if it will work as I want. (The LED matrix doesnt need anything extra as it has a signal wire for controling).

Comment: the power for the LEDs in a WS2812 matrix never goes through the microcontroller; that's the beauty of the WS2812: you control it through a serial data bus, not by supplying it power.

Comment: and: whenever you need significant output power, and are battery driven, linear drivers are not an option, as they burn all the voltage difference between in- and output as heat. So, go for a buck SMPS and you're fine.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for your fast response! I did a quick search of "buck SMPS" and I either saw the typical ebay buck converter boards or linear voltage regulators. Would you mind giving me an example or pointing me to some resources?

Comment: SMPS = switch mode power supply. So, the exact opposite of a linear regulator.

Comment: Ah, perhaps something like LM2576 ?

Comment: [Buck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter) converters is the most common architecture of SMPSes. There's literally thousands of chips that implement a controller, and you'd pick your electronic distributor's inventory's cheapest choice that fulfills your input/output voltage, current and regulation requirement, and build the regulator schematic from its datasheet.

Comment: yeah, the LM2576 is one (pretty old) example.

Comment: The 16x16 LED matrix can draw 15A if you turn it fully on! Not only will a battery barely last (a 2600 mAh 18650 will be dead by 10 minutes), you will need a very strong regulator. Will you limit the brightness or the number of LED elements turned on at any single time? Anyway, consider a non adjustable "Point Of Load" buck converter like this one. This one can do upto 8A if you follow their guidelines https://www.pololu.com/product/4091

Comment: Hi @AnasMalas , yes I am setting the brightness to less than 4% (however that is defined in the FastLed library). You think a battery will not suffice? Also, the circuit you shared seems to be based on a different chip to the LM2576 mentioned above: is it a better choice?

Comment: At 4% brightness, you would need 0.6A for the matrix. That's better! The module I shared is switching, it is better since it is more effecieint. You can buy something like it and solder it directly to your board. If you only need 1A, maybe this module is better for you as it can do upto 4A, and thus you wouldnt need to worry about power:
https://www.pololu.com/product/3782

Comment: Regarding your buzzer and mosfet, what buzzer are you using?

Comment: For the buzzer I was thinking of using a FUET-9650B-5V that I found on the EasyEDA catalog to send to JLCPCB. Rated at 30mA according to datasheet. The microcontroller is rated to 0.3mA which to me seems very low. I guess I can estimate 10ma?